# ModelChoiceField. ID instead of the name

Tags: django

In `send_option` (in views) variable I have `name` of `Send`.
I would like to have `ID` of `Send`

How to do it? Thanks

Form:

```
class SendOrderForm(forms.Form):
   send_option = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Send.objects.all())
```

Model:

```
class Send(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

Views:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SendOrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            send_option = form.cleaned_data['send_option']
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you can do is,

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SendOrderForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        send_option = form.cleaned_data['send_option'].id
```

`form.cleaned_data['send_option']` would get the object, and you can get its `id`  by doing a `.pk` or `.id`

Answer (score 0):

Does your `Send` model has `__unicode__` or `__str__` method that returns `name` of the instance?

If so, you need to return `id` of instance rather than `name`.

Comment: is it a good idea to change the __unicode__ proprerty? then he will have to go in, and change code everywhere he is displaying the object in the application