# ModelForm for choicefield with PK instead of usernames

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have a form generated by a **PostView**

```
class HotelCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Hotel
    fields = ['hotel', 'code', 'collaborateurs', 'planning' 'payday']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.manager_hotel = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The model **collaborateurs** is a choicefield which render the usernames.

I want this field to render PK instead so I tried to create my own form but could not figure out.

**forms.py**

```
 from django import forms 
 from .models import Hotel

class HotelForm(forms.Form):
   collaborateurs = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=collaborateurs.objects.all())
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean forms.ChoiceField not forms.ColleagueChoiceField?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. but even with that there is no change to my form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ModelChoiceField. ID instead of the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689129/modelchoicefield-id-instead-of-the-name)

Comment: I tried it but does not work for my case : 

`class HotelCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Hotel
    fields = ['hotel','code','collaborateurs', 'planning','payday']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.manager_hotel = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
        Hotel = form.cleaned_data['collaborateurs'].id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to create a custom widget.

Create a "widgets" folder and "pk-select.html" in some "templates" folder.

widgets/pk-select.html

```
<select name="{{ widget.name }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>
  {% for group_name, group_choices, group_index in widget.optgroups %}
    {% if group_name %}
      <optgroup label="{{ group_name }}">
    {% endif %}
    {% for option in group_choices %}
      <option value="{{ option.value|stringformat:'s' }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>{{ option.value }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if group_name %}
      </optgroup>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Then, modify your "form.py" like this

form.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.widgets import Select
from .models import Hotel


class PkSelect(Select):
    template_name = 'widgets/pk-select.html'


class HotelCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Hotel
        fields = ['hotel', 'code', 'collaborateurs', 'planning', 'payday']
        widgets = {
            'collaborateurs': PkSelect(attrs={})
        }
```

Next, I want you to make a bit change on "view.py"

view.py

```
class HotelCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = HotelCreateForm
    template_name = 'hotel_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.manager_hotel = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Which part made the change is this row inside the "pk-select.html"

```
<option value="{{ option.value|stringformat:'s' }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>{{ option.value }}</option>
```

Initially, `{{ option.value }}` was `{{ widget.label }}` as you can see on the GitHub page.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/select_option.html

`{{ widget.label }}` shows username in this case, so I modified this part.

I hope this is what you are looking for, feel free to ask me if my understanding is wrong.